# rake gitlab:setup fails on RHEL 5 with a compiled version of libicu

Tags: ruby, rubygems, gitlab

So I'm totally a Rails newbie. And this might be more of a linux question... Since the issue seems to revolve around libicu-devel and the charlock_holmes gem.

I've been following these too guides primarily (along with Google searches of course). I've got Rails 4 on Ruby 2 from RVM. And it's a RHEL5 install at Rackspace (dedicated). 
https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlabhq/blob/5-4-stable/doc/install/installation.md
http://blog.lsong.org/2013/07/install-gitlab-on-centos-6/

After having a few issues along the way I thought I was making progress until I got to grabbing packages from yum and the fact that there doesn't seem to be a package of libicu past 3.6 anywhere. I compiled that from source and everything seemed to install OK. The charlock_holmes gem was added.

But then after adding the DB stuff for GitLab I went to initialize things and can't go any further and now I have no idea what to do. I've found references to other errors at this point but they're usually from the DB not being setup properly so they're not helpful.

Anyone with more Rails experience than me know what I can do next?

```
rvmsudo -u git -H bundle exec rake gitlab:setup RAILS_ENV=production
rake aborted!
/home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/charlock_holmes-0.6.9.4/lib/charlock_holmes/charlock_holmes.so: undefined symbol: _ZN7icu_4_28ByteSink15GetAppendBufferEiiPciPi - /home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/charlock_holmes-0.6.9.4/lib/charlock_holmes/charlock_holmes.so
/home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require'
/home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `block in require'
/home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:236:in `load_dependency'
/home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require'
/home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/charlock_holmes-0.6.9.4/lib/charlock_holmes.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
/home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require'
/home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `block in require'
/home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:236:in `load_dependency'
/home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require'
/home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/gitlab-grit-2.5.1/lib/grit.rb:79:in `<top (required)>'
/home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require'
/home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `block in require'
/home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:236:in `load_dependency'
/home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require'
/home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/gitlab_git-1.3.0/lib/gitlab_git.rb:4:in `<top (required)>'
/home/jharvey/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@global/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:72:in `require'
/home/jharvey/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@global/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:72:in `block (2 levels) in require'
/home/jharvey/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@global/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:70:in `each'
/home/jharvey/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@global/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:70:in `block in require'
/home/jharvey/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@global/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:59:in `each'
/home/jharvey/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@global/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:59:in `require'
/home/jharvey/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@global/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler.rb:132:in `require'
/home/git/gitlab/config/application.rb:9:in `<top (required)>'
/home/git/gitlab/Rakefile:5:in `require'
/home/git/gitlab/Rakefile:5:in `<top (required)>'
/home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/rake_module.rb:25:in `load'
/home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/rake_module.rb:25:in `load_rakefile'
/home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/application.rb:589:in `raw_load_rakefile'
/home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/application.rb:89:in `block in load_rakefile'
/home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/application.rb:160:in `standard_exception_handling'
/home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/application.rb:88:in `load_rakefile'
/home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/application.rb:72:in `block in run'
/home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/application.rb:160:in `standard_exception_handling'
/home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/application.rb:70:in `run'
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

Let me know if I need to add more information. I tried adding the `--trace` flag and got the same output. I'm **guessing** on the libicu/charlock_holmes being the problem since it's the first message after `rake aborted!`.

My company won't spring for anything like Github enterprise and I was hoping to build a subdomain with some tools to share code with our numerous divisions. At the rate I'm going I might as well write a new app from scratch. Thanks in advance!

<strike>**Update:** Ran `:check` with `--trace` and noticed while most of it was the same, there were a few extra lines at the end.</strike>

**Update 2:** Tried the two suggestions. Switched to 1.9.3 and ran the `bundle config` command (no output). Ran trace again, and here's the result.

```
rvmsudo -u git -H bundle exec rake gitlab:check RAILS_ENV=production --trace
rake aborted!
/home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/charlock_holmes-0.6.9.4/lib/charlock_holmes/charlock_holmes.so: undefined symbol: _ZN7icu_4_28ByteSink15GetAppendBufferEiiPciPi - /home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/charlock_holmes-0.6.9.4/lib/charlock_holmes/charlock_holmes.so
/home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require'
/home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support    /dependencies.rb:251:in `block in require'
/home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:236:in `load_dependency'
/home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require'
/home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/charlock_holmes-0.6.9.4/lib/charlock_holmes.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
/home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require'
/home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `block in require'
/home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:236:in `load_dependency'
/home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require'
/home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/gitlab-grit-2.5.1/lib/grit.rb:79:in `<top (required)>'
/home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require'
/home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `block in require'
/home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:236:in `load_dependency'
/home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require'
/home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/gitlab_git-1.3.0/lib/gitlab_git.rb:4:in `<top (required)>'
/home/jharvey/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448@global/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:72:in `require'
/home/jharvey/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448@global/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:72:in `block (2 levels) in require'
/home/jharvey/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448@global/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:70:in `each'
/home/jharvey/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448@global/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:70:in `block in require'
/home/jharvey/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448@global/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:59:in `each'
/home/jharvey/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448@global/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:59:in `require'
/home/jharvey/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448@global/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler.rb:132:in `require'
/home/git/gitlab/config/application.rb:9:in `<top (required)>'
/home/git/gitlab/Rakefile:5:in `require'
/home/git/gitlab/Rakefile:5:in `<top (required)>'
/home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/rake_module.rb:25:in `load'
/home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/rake_module.rb:25:in `load_rakefile'
/home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/application.rb:589:in `raw_load_rakefile'
/home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/application.rb:89:in `block in load_rakefile'
/home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/application.rb:160:in `standard_exception_handling'
/home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/application.rb:88:in `load_rakefile'
/home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/application.rb:72:in `block in run'
/home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/application.rb:160:in `standard_exception_handling'
/home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/application.rb:70:in `run'
/home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.0.4/bin/rake:33:in `<top (required)>'
/home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/bin/rake:23:in `load'
/home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/bin/rake:23:in `<main>'
```

**Update 3:** Making progress. I seem to have successfully got everything installed after messing around with redis for a bit. I can check the "env:info" successfully. However now I try and get gitlab online using `init.d` and it's not working. =/ There was no init script after install so I grabbed one from gitlabhq per this post, [GitLab installation on linux](http://www.linuxcrafts.com/2013/05/gitlab-installation-on-linux.html) (using 5-4 like my install). That script results in:

```
/etc/init.d/gitlab start
bash: bundle: command not found`
```

We'll see if I can sort that out. I welcome any help.

**Update 4:** Sorted that out. RVM couldn't be seen by the git user. Haven't tested every aspect of the system but I now have GitLab running on a git subdomain. Don't have a specific answer to the original question. But I seem to have gotten to the end of the journey. *crosses fingers*

Comment: Yes, this has nothing to do with rails; I've removed the `ruby-on-rails` tag.

Comment: Have you run the `bundle config build.charlock_holmes --with-icu-dir=/path/to/installed/icu4c` command like the README says? Do you have icu4c installed?

Comment: Ruby 2.0? You need ruby1.9.3-p392

Comment: @Deefour Yes, icu4c is installed, as I mentioned I installed it from source when no yum package was available from a repository. Where in the guide does it mention `bundle config build.charlock_holmes --with-icu-dir=/path/to/installed/icu4c`? I *did* run `sudo gem install charlock_holmes --version '0.6.9.4'` like the guide says. But I'll give that a go.

Comment: @VonC: That's still a requirement? I saw something from months ago referencing an issue with 2.0. I was just happy to get away from the ridiculously old version that yum was giving me. I'll try that too. Thanks!

Comment: Tried installing libicu from rpms I downloaded (`localinstall`) and I'm currently removing the entire gitlab directory and trying from that point forward again... However, as of last month the Rails devs suggested moving to Ruby 2 if you're using Rails 4. Which is what I have. http://weblog.rubyonrails.org/2013/6/25/Rails-4-0-final/ Not sure what to make of that. =/

Comment: Hmm... Going back to the beginning, with 1.9.3 and using the RPM package of charlock_holmes and now it made it past that error. Of course, I'm now seeing issues with Redis, but at least I've inshed forward a bit. I'm not sure who writes these install guides but I now have a multitude and none have "redis-server", just "redis" and that seems to be missing things.

Answer (score 0):

For me, this was an LDD issue.  On my system, headers for libicui18n were installed, while both libicui18n.so.36 and libicui18n.so.42 were installed.

Validate this with

```
ldd vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/extensions/x86_64-linux/2.1.0-static/charlock_holmes-{YOUR VERSION HERE}/charlock_holmes/charlock_holmes.so
```

Look for the line

```
libicui18n.so.## => ...
```

If ## is 36, then bundler's linking against the wrong version (it should be 42).  Bundler seemed to be disregarding the --with-icu-dir flag.  Not sure why.

My fix was to use gem to compile charlock_holmes

```
gem install charlock_holmes -v '0.6.9.4' -- --with-icu-dir=[...]
```

where [...] was the path to the `lib` directory in which icu 42 was installed.  Then I just copied the generated binary (charlock_holmes.so) over the one produced by bundler.